# How To Stop Data Reloading On Refresh Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an interesting question that I believe has not been asked before, and should be a decent challenge for some of us. First off, I am new to firebase--about 2 days old (if that). I've been reading through the docs, but can't seem to find a straight answer.

**My Situation Is This:**
I am pulling user data from the realtime database, and it fills in many fields within my webpage.

**The Problem Is:**
Every time the page reloads (even on navigation changed between, say, `home.html` and `page2.html`) the areas are left blank until the script reloads the data.

**My Question Is:**
Is there a way where I can only load the data once, so that the problem will not reoccur?

**I Have Tried:**

1. Utilizing the `once()` function built into firebase. Did not work because the script is still called each time the page loads.

**Other Possible Solutions:**
Could I possibly store a variable that indicates whether or not the data has been send before? How would I do this?

Any ideas? Thanks all!

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider using [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

What session storage does is it enables you to save certain variables to a local cache that is not cleared until the browser is closed.  Local storage is used for the same thing, the only difference is it is not cleared when the browser is closed.

I think for this situation session storage would suffice as you wouldn't want the user data to be saved permanently just incase something changes.

To accomplish this task you could do something like

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem("updated")){
  // get the data from the session storage
} else {
  // get from firebase
  sessionStorage.setItem("updated",true);
}
```

whenever the page loads.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There's multiple ways to accomplish this. You can write a single page application so that each page is not a reload (look into angular, react, etc...), or you can use the browsers localStorage to store the results.